# Garbage collector problems when using GSON with Android

Tags: java, android, gson

When I attempt to convert a JSON string into a (very simple) Java object, my log starts filling up with an assortment of GC warnings.

The line which calls GSON:

```
this.response = gson.fromJson(reply, LoginResponse.class);
```

An example of the reply String:

```
{"success":true,"id":1,"username":"answerbox","email":"user@example.com","reputation":0}
```

And the LoginResponse class:

```
class LoginResponse extends Response {
    int id;
    String username;
    String email;
    int reputation;
}
```

Response is just a class with a single field success (boolean).
Here is a sample of the logs:

```
02-07 12:00:09.615 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 142203(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 17MB/28MB, paused 7.968ms total 89.450ms
02-07 12:00:10.809 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 224882(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 154(2MB) LOS objects, 37% free, 17MB/28MB, paused 17.605ms total 102.947ms
02-07 12:00:12.123 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 220969(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 285(5MB) LOS objects, 34% free, 18MB/28MB, paused 24.409ms total 129.519ms
02-07 12:00:13.447 26558-26565/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 67.351ms
02-07 12:00:13.460 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 207809(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 229(5MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 18MB/31MB, paused 31.546ms total 159.587ms
02-07 12:00:15.192 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.871ms
02-07 12:00:15.263 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 257203(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 244(6MB) LOS objects, 35% free, 20MB/31MB, paused 34.771ms total 178.536ms
02-07 12:00:16.837 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.630ms
02-07 12:00:16.893 26558-26565/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.057ms
02-07 12:00:16.901 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 239294(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 205(6MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 21MB/35MB, paused 29.837ms total 180.950ms
02-07 12:00:16.908 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.190ms
02-07 12:00:17.391 26558-26565/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.780ms
02-07 12:00:17.979 26558-26565/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.227ms
02-07 12:00:18.391 26558-26565/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.083ms
02-07 12:00:18.833 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.149ms
02-07 12:00:18.903 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 286095(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 220(7MB) LOS objects, 36% free, 22MB/35MB, paused 31.607ms total 158.192ms
02-07 12:00:18.912 26558-26569/xyz.cathal.answerbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.078ms
```

Anyone have any ideas? I am new to Android so apologies if it's glaring me in the face. If you need any more information technically or contextually let me know!

Comment: I don't see any problems neither in your code nor in the logs.

Comment: The problem is the line calling gson.fromJson never fully executes. The code execution simply halts at this line.

Comment: could you make sure that you know the content of `reply`? For example `Log` it before passing to `fromJSON`. Just to make sure that you receive what you expect.

Comment: Yeah I've done exactly that already! Copy and pasted from log to here.

Comment: @Cathal What does happen if your `reply` is not a `String` instance, but an instance of `Reader` or `JsonReader`?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv unfortunately the same thing. When I debug and set a few breakpoints, all of the variables and such disappear as soon as I step over to the gson line. Very confused atm.

Comment: Problem solved, stupid mistake.. I was instantiating the Gson object in caller's parent class, but not in its constructor.. Aaaaaggggghhhhh